# Python - API / wrapper function design pattern

Tags: python, exec

I'm implementing API which takes users' code and execute at my server.

For instance, user submits the code as following

```
push("item")
```

then I want to execute this string code in the users's context, such as

```
users_stack.push("item")
```

What would be the design pattern and how do I convert user's code this way?